# Unable to find an instance for the variable

Tags: coq

Context: I'm working on exercises in [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/).

```
Theorem neg_move : forall x y : bool,
  x = negb y -> negb x = y.
Proof. Admitted.

Theorem evenb_n__oddb_Sn : forall n : nat,
  evenb n = negb (evenb (S n)).
Proof.
  intros n. induction n as [| n'].
  Case "n = 0".
    simpl. reflexivity.
  Case "n = S n'".
    rewrite -> neg_move.
```

Before the last line, my subgoal is this:

```
evenb (S n') = negb (evenb (S (S n')))
```

And I want to transform it into this:

```
negb (evenb (S n')) = evenb (S (S n'))
```

When I try to step through `rewrite -> neg_move`, however, it produces this error:

> Error: Unable to find an instance for the variable y.

I'm sure this is really simple, but what am I doing wrong? (Please don't give anything away for solving `evenb_n__oddb_Sn`, unless I'm doing it completely wrong).

Comment: The phrase "unable to find an instance for the variable *y*" means that Coq is unable to find a value to substitute for the variable *y* in the type of *neg_move*. You can solve this problem by explicitly instantiating the parameters of *neg_move*, including the antecedent of the conditional (which will be generated as a subgoal if left uninstantiated). However, conditional statements are generally meant to be *applied*; in fact, *neg_move* can be applied to your induction hypothesis to obtain a more useful hypothesis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As danportin mentioned, Coq is telling you that it does not know how to instantiate `y`. Indeed, when you do `rewrite -> neg_move`, you ask it to replace some `negb x` by a `y`. Now, what `y` is Coq supposed to use here? It cannot figure it out.

One option is to instantiate `y` explicitly upon rewriting:

`rewrite -> neg_move with (y:=some_term)`

This will perform the rewrite and ask you to prove the premises, here it will add a subgoal of the form `x = negb some_term`.

Another option is to specialize `neg_move` upon rewriting:

`rewrite -> (neg_move _ _ H)`

Here `H` must be a term of type `some_x = negb some_y`. I put two wildcards for the `x` and the `y` parameters of `neg_move` since Coq is able to infer them from `H` as being `some_x` and `some_y` respectively. Coq will then try to rewrite an occurence of `negb some_x` in your goal with `some_y`.
But you first need to get this `H` term in your hypotheses, which might be some additional burden...

(Note that the first option I gave you should be equivalent to `rewrite -> (neg_move _ some_term)`)

Another option is `erewrite -> negb_move`, which will add uninstantiated variables that will look like `?x` and `?y`, and try to do the rewrite. You will then have to prove the premise, which will look like `(evenb (S (S n'))) = negb ?y`, and hopefully in the process of solving this subgoal, Coq will find out what `?y` should have been from the start (there are some restrictions though, and some problems may arise is Coq solves the goal without figuring out what `?y` must be).

---

However, for your particular problem, it is quite easier:

```
==========
evenb (S n') = negb (evenb (S (S n')))
```

`symmetry.`

```
==========
negb (evenb (S (S n'))) = evenb (S n')
```

`apply neg_move.`

```
==========
evenb (S (S n')) = negb (evenb (S n'))
```

And that's what you wanted (backwards, do another `symmetry.` if you care).